# Bash Shell Script Remote Background Processing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, video, ffmpeg

I Have Created a Bash Shell script.. With that i can crop and convert video locally..

```
nohup ffmpeg -i "$c1" -vf "$crop_value1" -b 1800k "/home/Cropped/""$name1"_cropped.mp4"" > crop1.txt &
PID1=$!
nohup ffmpeg -i "$c2" -vf "$crop_value2" -b 1800k "/home/Cropped/""$name2"_cropped.mp4"" > crop2.txt &
PID2=$!
nohup ffmpeg -i "$c3" -vf "$crop_value3" -b 1800k "/home/Cropped/""$name3"_cropped.mp4"" > crop3.txt &
PID3=$!
nohup ffmpeg -i "$c4" -vf "$crop_value4" -b 1800k "/home/Cropped/""$name4"_cropped.mp4"" > crop4.txt &
PID4=$!
wait $PID1
wait $PID2
wait $PID3
wait $PID4
```

As Above Code Shows Im Using 4 Conversion In background In Local Server And I'm Using Wait PID To Check Whether Conversation Finished Or Not.

My Problem Is Its taking very late to Convert.. So I Thinking Of Converting One Conversion In Local Sever And Another Three In Different Remote Server Through SSH 
Example:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 "nohup ffmpeg -i "$c1" -vf "$crop_value1" -b 1800k "/home/Cropped/""$name1"_cropped.mp4"" > crop1.txt &"
```

My Problem Is After Executing Remote Commands How Can I Get Remote PID And Use PID Wait Option For All Remote Connection.

Comment: Why Do You Capitallize Every Word In The Sentence?

Comment: Don't put the remote command in the background, just put the `ssh` command in the background.

Comment: SSH Command In The Background? I cant understand

Answer (score 1):

Put the `ssh` command in the background, not the remote command:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 "nohup ffmpeg -i "$c1" -vf "$crop_value1" -b 1800k \
    "/home/Cropped/""$name1"_cropped.mp4"" > crop1.txt" &
PID1=$!
```

BTW, you don't need a `wait` command for each background process. If you run `wait` with no argument, it waits for all background processes.

Comment: I need to wait for all background process to finish so im using PID wait..because my next command needs cropped videos as input

Comment: That's what it does, it waits for all background processes to finish.